# iPad not selecting all text inside a text input on tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

Ok, this seems to be a simple request, but I am not finding it to be so.  I just want it so when an html input[type="text"] is focused (tapped in ios), all text is selected (like any normal browser).  I have looked around and found a couple suggestions, but nothing seems to work - here is what I have tried:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
}).mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also tried this:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
}).mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I have read that the mouseup event on ios does funky stuff, but I am not sure.  Any ideas?

Comment: you are only using jquery? im not so sure that you should be using mouse events. maybe jquery mobile its worth a try

Comment: I am using focus because I want to cover clicks, taps and tabs into a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function() {
    this.select(); //no jquery wrapper
}).mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why not using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) `tap` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=text], textarea").on("tap", function() {
        this.select();
    }).vmouseup(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

Comment: how do I do this/load mobile only if it is ios?

Comment: @naspinski it is compatible with ios : http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/features.html